# Internet response time spikes

Tags: linux, vmware

I have a (VMWare) virtual linux server running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. It is running at an external hosting provider.

This server is running Nagios to monitor some other (external) web services. I am experiencing frequent response time spikes that I cannot explain.

The sites being monitored are actually OK and respond to http requests very fast (checked using physical machine / browser). It's just that http requests from my virtual linux server to these (external) web sites are sometimes very fast, sometimes very slow.

To test this, I ran the follwoing command :

```
for i in {1..60};do curl -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total}\\n http://74.125.136.99; sleep 10; done
```

Note that I am using an IP address (www.google.com), no URL, to rule out DNS lookup problems.

The output looks like this mostly :

```
0.017
0.017
0.014
7.024
1.013
63.126
15.048
7.032
0.016
0.016
```

etcetera...

These spikes occur very often.

Does anyone have any ideas where to look ?

I have already tried the same command using an internal website, and the slowdowns do not occur in that case. So it seems to be just internet connections that slow down periodically.

Ubuntu is not running a firewall (sudo ufw status is returning "inactive").

I tried disabling ipv6 (http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/disable-ipv6-if-your-internet-is.html). This did not help.

I created a ticket with my hosting provider. Maybe the issue originates in their internet connection, but I kind of doubt that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a routing problem at the hosting provider. Not related to the Linux server at all...